# Struct field reverts

Tags: unit-testing, go, struct

I'm playing with Go a bit but found this weird situation while doing some tests.

I'm using method in a struct to send a variable to another method that should change a field, but when I check it at the end, the field goes back to the first value, which has me confused.

```
func (this TVManager) sendMessage(message string) {
    fmt.Println("5", this.connector)
    payload := map[string]string {
       "id": "0",
       "type": "request",
       "uri": "ssap://system.notifications/createToast",
       "payload": "{'message': 'This is a message'}"}
    this.connector.sendCommand(payload)
    fmt.Println("4", this.connector)
}
```

This is the method I'm testing, it calls sendCommand of connector.

```
func (this MockConnector) sendCommand(payload map[string]string) {
    fmt.Println("0", this)
    this.last_command = payload
    this.value = true
    fmt.Println("0", this)
}
```

Which in the mock object I'm using is simply changing the value of this struct fields.

```
    manager.sendMessage("This is a message")

fmt.Println("1", connector)
assert.Equal(t, expected, connector.last_command, "Command should be equal")
```

But when I check it, it goes back to internal. I set some prints to try an d track the values and they change the values as expected, but then it reverts.

```
 1 {false map[]}
 5 {false map[]}
 0 {false map[]}
 0 {true map[uri:ssap://system.notifications/createToast payload:{'message': 'This is a message'} id:0 type:request]}
 4 {false map[]}
 1 {false map[]}
 --- FAIL: TestTVManagerSendsNotificationDownToConnector (0.00s)
```

This is just a small program I'm going over to learn some Go, so I appreciate any help anybody could give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the structures by value. This works fine so long as you are not modifying the structure, but if you do modify it you are actually only modifying a copy. To make this work you need to use *pointers* to the structures you need to modify.

Instead of:

```
func (this MockConnector) sendCommand(payload map[string]string)
```

Use:

```
func (this *MockConnector) sendCommand(payload map[string]string)
```

Also, it is considered a bad idea to use `this` (or `self`) as a receiver name in Go, as a receiver is not the same thing as a `this` pointer/reference in other languages.

Another best practice, is if one method for a given type needs a pointer receiver, all methods for that type should have pointer receivers. This is so that the method set remains consistent no matter if the value is a pointer or not.

See [method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets), and [these](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers) [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets) [answers](https://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that it had something to do with that, but tried to pass a pointer to the actual payload like this func (this MockConnector) sendCommand (*payload map[string]string) I'm coming from a Python background so pointers are something I need to get used to.

Comment: Also can I use anything as the receiver name? There is no expected community good code name for a receiver? That's somehow.... liberating. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use anything you want, in this case I would use `mock` or `conn` or something similar, but that's just me... A good rule of thumb is to pretend it is a parameter when picking a name.